# User based Collaborative Filtering (with Python)

Tags: python, matrix, recommender-system

I am trying to understand how can I calculate the similarity between `userid` and `itemid`. Here is the user-based table.The table didn't have rating /score information.

`userid | itemid1 | itemid2 | itemid3 ... | itemid10000`

`1      | 1       | 0       | 1           | 1`

`2      | 0       | 1       | 1           | 1`

`3      | 0       | 0       | 0           | 1`

1)Can I still use KNN method (like `manhattan distance` or `euclidean distance`)  and `cosine similarity` method to calculate the similarity score? If so,how can I get these scores as vector matrix.

2)Suppose we have itemid > `100,000,000`, so the table is very sparse. So do we have any method to control sparse data to deal with collaborative filtering problems.

Answer (score 1):

Basically with kNN approach you cannot compute similarity between user and product. You can compute similarity between user-user or product-product to give recommendations. kNN methods dont deal really well with sparse matrices, for such matrices matrix decomposition algorithms are better. Here is a good Python library called [Surprise Python](http://surpriselib.com/) with implementations of kNN based algorithms, matrix factorization based algorithms and many more.